# NullPointerException in static init block when WAR build/deploy to WildFly via Maven

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly

i am trying to build and deploy a WAR to JBoss via maven. When im build/deploy via IntellJ everything works fine.

Deployed via Maven i get this Stacktrace:

```
018-02-20 16:59:09,863 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /akkredit-1/akkredit:  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at de.akkredit.Akkreditor$3.<init>(Akkreditor.java:109)
at de.akkredit.Akkreditor.getModules(Akkreditor.java:106)
at de.akkredit.Akkreditor.akkredit(Akkreditor.java:135)
at de.akkredit.service.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:48)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.akkredit.tools.Tools.<clinit>(Tools.java:41)
... 44 more
```

Tools is a Class with static functions and static initializing block:

```
    try {
        String xslt = Tools.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/transform.xslt").getFile();
        xsltTransformer = tf.newTransformer( new StreamSource( new File( xslt ) ) );
        <line 41:> xsltTransformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes" );
        xsltTransformer.setOutputProperty( "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2" );
        xsltTransformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.ENCODING,"UTF-8" );
        xsltTransformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes" );
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
```

See line41

I do think that happens because the resource transform.xslt was not found

The file is located in src/main/resources

in the WAR: WEB-INF/classes/

would appreciate if anyone could give me a hint here.

Regards

Alex

Comment: Try and remove the "/" before "transform.xslt". Also use this to get the resource instead of what you are doing right now (it's safer) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(...). Also stacic blocks like that are evil, avoid them at all cost, if you need it just use a static private method and assign the result of the method to your static field.

Comment: hi, thanks for response. i've already tried this before, unfortunatly having same results. regarding static initialization: could you give me some background info? all functions in the class are static and used by classes troughout the whole project, only the transformer needed initialization.. as static functions are thread-safe i thought it would be a good idea. You think its generally not a good idea or only in javaEE context? thanks in advance

Comment: Static initialization blocks cannot be tested, that's why it is discouraged everywhere. In the context of a Java EE application here you should avoid using static utility class for anything business related, if you provide create a basic service with interface and implementation then now you can handle XML and in the future you can have an implementation that handle JSON and it will be easier to integrate to your existing application. Also it might depends on the implementation but I'm not sure Transformer are thread-safe, in the context of a Java EE application that can be a big issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String xslt = Tools.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/transform.xslt").getFile();
    xsltTransformer = tf.newTransformer( new StreamSource( new File( xslt ) ) );
```

If the resource resides in the WAR-file, the returned resource will be something like `C:/some/dir/to/the/webapp/WebApp.war!/transform.xslt` that can't be opened with `java.io.File`.

Use `getResourceAsStream` instead and pass the returned `InputStream` to your `StreamSource`. The method returns `null` if the resource can't be found, so might check that and log that instead of letting the whole thing crash again with a `NullPointerException`. If that happens, you might try changing the resource to look for, e.g. to `transform.xslt` (i.e. without the leading slash) or really make sure that the resource is actually in the war-file where it's supposed to be.

BTW: You have mentioned "line 41" but I don't see any information in your code what line 41 actually is, so I assumed that

1. undeployed, i.e. residing in a directory on your test system, everything works as expected
2. That line 41 is actually the line with `new StreamSource( new File( xslt ) )` and the `NullPointerException` comes from there.

BTW2: You said

> The file is located in src/main/resources
>
> in the WAR: WEB-INF/classes/

Does that mean that your resource resides in the directory `src/main/resources` that itself is located in `WEB-INF/classes` in your war-file? In that case you need to change the resource to look for to `/src/main/resources/transform.xslt`. If you meant that it's residing in the former directory while you do your tests and it resides in the latter when deployed as WAR, never mind ;-)

Comment: hi, thanks for response! i've tagged line 41 with "<line 41:>" in the try block. @BTW2: in original project structure the file is located in src/main/resources, after packaging its located in WEB-INF/classes/ in the WAR. sorry for the ambiguous statement. Im gonna give it a try! the file is definitly in the war-file!

Comment: I think, the transformer is still NULL because Line 40 didn't work out. Your Explanation seems legit.